# Plotting history of accuracy in BaggingClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I've trained a simple random forest algorithm and bagging classifier (n_estimators = 100). Is it possible to plot the history of accuracy in bagging Classifier? How to calculate the variance of in 100 samples?

I've just printed the accuracy value for both algorithms:

```
# DecisionTree
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.90)
clf2 = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf2.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
pred2 = clf2.predict(X_test)
acc2  = clf2.score(X_test, y_test)
acc2  # 0.6983930778739185

# Bagging
clf3 = BaggingClassifier(tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(),  max_samples=0.5, max_features=0.5, n_estimators=100,\
                         verbose=2)
clf3.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
pred3 = clf3.predict(X_test)
acc3=clf3.score(X_test,y_test)
acc3 # 0.911619283065513
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "history of accuracy"?

Comment: Therorically bagging train many model, each model has a accuracy which change based on the n_estimators. I want to get plot like this. 
[link](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*4DggM7mvm8IhuTbwvWzMrQ.png) using load_digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can get this information from the fitted `BaggingClassifier`. But you can create such a plot by fitting for different `n_estimators`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, X_test, y, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data,
                                        iris.target,
                                        test_size=0.20)

estimators = list(range(1, 20))
accuracy = []

for n_estimators in estimators:
    clf = BaggingClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1),
                            max_samples=0.2,
                            n_estimators=n_estimators)
    clf.fit(X, y)
    acc = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
    accuracy.append(acc)

plt.plot(estimators, accuracy)
plt.xlabel("Number of estimators")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
plt.show()
```

(Of course, the iris dataset is easily fit with just a single `DecisionTreeClassifier`, so I set `max_depth=1` in this example.)

For a statistically meaningful result, you should fit a `BaggingClassifier` multiple times for each `n_estimators` and take the average of the obtained accuracies.

Comment: Thanks this helped me well.